# reflection trim all strings in list with list c#

Tags: c#, string, list, reflection, trim

I have a method with trim all strings in first level.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Trim<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        var stringProperties = item.GetType().GetProperties()
                  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

        foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            var currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue(item, null);

            if (currentValue != null)
                stringProperty.SetValue(item, currentValue.Trim(), null);
        }
    }
    return collection;
}
```

But if my property is a List I need apply trim in all string properties in this list, someone help me?

Comment: why not use recursion?

Comment: You could probably do this a little easier with a combination of SelectMany to flatten your object and .OfType<string>() to select all string values, then trim each.

Comment: @StephenBrickner That wouldn't work because `string` is immutable.

Comment: You really need to make your method lazy by using `yield return item` at the end of the `foreach` or change it to except something like `ICollection<T>` as it stands it will iterate the `IEnumerable<T>` when called and just return the same `IEnumerable<T>` which is fine if the underlying type is something like `List<T>`, but it could be a sequence that generates it's items each time you iterate it, meaning you'd lose all the changes.

Comment: And what if property is of type `List<List<List<List<string>>>>`  ? What depth should it use ?

Comment: "But if my property is a List" a list of what?  Strings?  Other objects?  What about structs?  Why are you having to subversively trim all strings anyway?

Comment: List of object with strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Trim<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    where T:class 
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();

        // Loop over properts
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof (string))
            {
                var currentValue = (string)property.GetValue(item);
                if (currentValue != null)
                    property.SetValue(item, currentValue.Trim());
            }
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                var currentValue = (IEnumerable<object>)property.GetValue(item);
                if (currentValue != null)
                    currentValue.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Edit: Included yield

Edit2: Removed yield again. I know this is bad practice for IEnumerable extensions. However the alternative would be:

```
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                var currentValue = (IEnumerable<object>)property.GetValue(item);
                if (currentValue != null)
                    currentValue.Trim().ToList(); // Hack to enumerate it!
            }
        }
    }
    yield return item;
}
```

Comment: It is recursive if I am not mistaken. Reaching a collection I call Trim() on the new collection and it starts again.

Comment: Yeah, I misread, but you do need to set the nested `IEnumerable` to make sure the lazy implementation takes.

Comment: This won't work. Due to covariance I can cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` but I can't set it in properties of type `List<Foo>` for example. However you are right. Right now it does nothing.

Comment: 'var currentValue = (IEnumerable<object>)property.GetValue(item);' in this case currentValue is same object, so you can not call Trim() method.

Comment: Why is it the same object? `(IEnumerable<object>)property.GetValue(item)` reads the property value from instance `item`. Therefore it is not the same or am I wrong?

Comment: Never mind. I think the naming is quite confusing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to alter the strings in place in the source collection(s), as shown in your example, then I think the simplest approach might be to add an additional extension method to specifically handle Lists of strings, that in turn utilizes the extension method from your example, altered to be specific to IEnumerables of strings.  The new extension method would be pretty simple, like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> Trim( this IEnumerable<List<string>> collection )
{
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        item.Trim();
    }
    return collection;
}
```

And your extension would get tweaked like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Trim( this IEnumerable<string> collection )
{
    foreach( var item in collection )
    {
        var stringProperties = item.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where( p => p.PropertyType == typeof( string ) );

        foreach( var stringProperty in stringProperties )
        {
            var currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue( item, null );

            if( currentValue != null )
                stringProperty.SetValue( item, currentValue.Trim(), null );
        }
    }
    return collection;
}
```

I kept your pattern of returning the original collection, I assume this is to provide some type of method chaining that you desire.

Of course, this does not handle recursion but from what I've seen that isn't a requirement here.